# Ветвление в python

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Условие задачи: 
Напишите программу. Дано целое число **`К`** в диапазоне 0–100. Вывести описание оценки: 0-59 - «Провал», 60-74 – «С», 75-89 - «В», 90-100 - «А» .

Ввожу число баллов он просто выводит те числа, которые вписал, а должен выдавать оценку А или B.

```
a = int(input("Введите количество баллов:"))

norm_a= [90, 100]
norm_b= [75, 89]
norm_c= [60, 74]
norm_p= [0, 59]

if a >= norm_a[0] and a<= norm_a[1]:
    print ("A")
elif a >= norm_b[0] and a<= norm_b[1]:
    print("B")
elif a >= norm_c[0] and a<= norm_c[1]:
    print("C")
elif a >= norm_p[0] and a<= norm_p[1]:
    print("Fail")
```

Comment: У меня вывел буквы. Ввел 95, вывелось A. Проверьте, что вы именно этот скрипт запускаете

Comment: Получается ошибки в коде нету ?

Comment: у меня тоже при 76 осталось на экране: "Введите количество баллов:B"

Comment: описанной ошибки в коде нет, он рабочий

Comment: По-видимому, вы не понимаете где ввод и вывод.

Comment: Плюсую к тому, что скрипт работает. Единственное, добавлю что вместо
a >= norm_a[0] and a<= norm_a[1]
можно написать просто
norm_a[0] <= a <= norm_a[1]. Работает так же, но выглядит более читабельно

Comment: Ну так Enter нажми, ёмаё 

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что автор запутался.

Answer (score 3):

Код рабочий, но вообще можно проще и универсальнее тоже самое написать:

```
a = int(input("Введите количество баллов:"))

norm = {
    'A': [90, 100],
    'B': [75, 89],
    'C': [60, 74],
    'Fail': [0, 59]
}

for k,v in norm.items():
    a1, a2 = v
    if a in range(a1, a2+1):
        print(k)
        break
```

Всегда старайтесь использовать принцип `DRY` - если код повторяется, то наверняка его можно сократить до перебора какой-то коллекции.

Хотя с `range` я, конечно, извратился, тоже самое можно написать как:

```py
    if a1 <= a <= a2:
```

Но вариант с `range` мне кажется более понятным по сути - мы проверяем, что целое число попадает в некий диапазон.

Comment: Ваш вариант работает почти в два раза медленнее

Comment: @andreymal О, точно, надо ж `break` ещё добавить. Сама по себе проверка через `range` не может быть сильно медленнее, `range` под такие проверки оптимизирован.

Comment: С добавленным break стало в 1.6 раза медленнее

Comment: (а вообще я субъективно считаю хорошим только вариант `if a >= a1 and a <= a2`, потому что другие варианты заставляют напрягать мозг специфическими особенностями питонячьей логики и питонячьего парсера выражений)

Comment: @andreymal А меня наоборот вариант с `and` заставляет задумываться - что и с чем мы сравниваем вообще. Но так да, я даже специально проверил - перебор словаря медленнее. Но зато универсальнее.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код совершенно нормально работает, всё правильно. Я проверил

```
К = int( input( 'Введите количество баллов:' ) )
norm_a = [ 90, 100 ]
norm_b = [ 75,  89 ]
norm_c = [ 60,  74 ]
norm_p = [  0,  59 ]

if   norm_a[0] <= К <= norm_a[1] :
  print( 'A' )
elif norm_b[0] <= К <= norm_b[1] :
  print( 'B' )
elif norm_c[0] <= К <= norm_c[1] :
  print( 'C' )
elif norm_p[0] <= К <= norm_p[1] :
  print( 'Провал' )

# Напишите программу
# Дано целое число К в диапазоне 0–100
# Вывести описание оценки:
# «А»     90 - 100
# «В»     75 -  89
# «С»     60 -  74
# «Провал» 0 -  59
```